# SDL and C++: Waiting for multiple threads to finish

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl

I am having trouble to fix the following problem:
I have 10 threads that don't need to interact with each other and therefore can all run simultaneusly.
I create them in a loop.
However I need to wait until all threads are done until I can continue with the code that starts after the for loop.
Here is the problem in pseudo code:

```
//start threads
for (until 10) {
    SDL_Thread* thread = SDL_CreateThread();
}
//the rest of the code starts here, all threads need to be done first
```

What's the best way to get this done?

I need to stay platform independent with that problem, that's why I try to only use SDL-functions.

If there is another platform independent solution for c++, I am fine with that too.

Comment: If you can use `C++11`, you can check out the thread support in `C++11` : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can take the following approach:

const int THREAD_COUNT = 10;
static int ThreadFunction(void *ptr);
{
    // Some useful work done by thread
    // Here it will sleep for 5 seconds and then exit
    sleep ( 5 );
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   vector<SDL_Thread*> threadIdVector;

   // create 'n' threads
   for ( int count = 0; count < THREAD_COUNT; count++ )
   {
       SDL_Thread *thread;
       stringstream ss;
       ss << "Thread::" <<  count;
       string tname = ss.str();
       thread = SDL_CreateThread( ThreadFunction, tname, (void *)NULL);
       if ( NULL != thread )
       {
           threadIdVector.push_back ( thread );
       }
   }

   // iterate through the vector and wait for each thread
   int tcount  = 0;
   vector<SDL_Thread*>::iterator iter;
   for ( iter = threadIdVector.begin();
                 iter != threadIdVector.end(); iter++ )
   {
       int  threadReturnValue;
       cout << "Main waiting for Thread : " << tcount++ << endl;

       SDL_WaitThread( *iter, &threadReturnValue);
   }

   cout << "All Thread have finished execution. Main will proceed...." << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I ran this program with standard posix libary commands and it worked fine. Then I replaced the posix library calls with SDL Calls. I do not have the SDL library so you may have to compile the code once.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but if the very first thread finishes before the last thread has been started, isn't it possible that it will miss some threads when iterating?
Otherwise I really like this approach because it's simple.

Comment: @Marius That will not be a problem. When the main creates a new thread it always adds it to the vector. So even if first thread finishes before last thread has been started, both the thread pointers will be pushed in the vector. So the size of the vector is guaranteed to be 10 before iteration starts. Now during iteration if 1st thread has already finished execution, the wait call will immediately return and main thread will now wait for next thread. So  main will only wait for that thread which is still executing and for others will return immediately which is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a Semaphor which increments for every running thread, if the thread is done it decrements the Semaphor and your main programm waits until it is 0.

There are plenty example how semaphore is implemented and by that it will be platform independent.